# How to set up a monthly reset function in a database

Tags: database, postgresql, reset, pg-cron

I am trying to create a function in my postgres database to reset, at the beginning of each month, the column **nbr_requests** of my table **users**, the structure of which is as follows:

```
users : {
    id: SERIAL,
    full_name: VARCHAR(255),
    nbr_requests: INT,
    max_requests: INT
}
```

I tried to install **pg_cron**, a postgres extension to do this and I created a schedule:
`SELECT * FROM cron.schedule('0 0 1 * *', $$UPDATE users SET nbr_requests = 0$$);`
But that doesn't do anything and I encounter an error ***"connection failed"***... while I added these lines in my *pg_hba.conf* file:

```
host   all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host   all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

I added these lines in my *postgresql.conf* file:

```
shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_cron'
cron.database_name = 'nv_api_db'
cron.timezone = 'CET'
```

And before running the query `CREATE EXTENSION pg_cron;`, I restarted the postgres service and logged in database as **superuser** with psql.

Comment: To your question add as text the answers to the following: 1) Are you running `pg_cron` in the `nv_api_db` database? 2) Did you `reload` the Postgres server when you changed the `pg_hba.conf` file? 3) What does the Postgres log show when the job runs? 4) What does `select * from cron.job_run_details` show?

Comment: Unless you have no other choice than to use pg_cron, use an OS level scheduling tool like cron